# How to avoid subfolders creation while zipping files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, python-zipfile

I am trying to zip the files from the list `localpath_list` in to one zip file `reports.zip.

It works as expected, but when I extract the `reports.zip` file, there are folders created inside it.

i.e all the .xls files are under `files/sample/`.

what I need is just the .xls files without any folder structure.

```
localpath_list = ["files/sample/sample1.xls", "files/sample/sample2.xls", "files/sample/sample3.xls"]
with zipfile.ZipFile(fr"downloads/reports.zip", 'w') as zipF:
    for file in localpath_list:
        zipF.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to: [[Python.Docs]: zipfile - ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None, compresslevel=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Write the file named *filename* to the archive, **giving it the archive name *arcname*** (by default, this will be the same as *filename*, ...

So you should use:

```py
zipF.write(file, arcname=os.path.basename(file), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

If expanding the functionality (to include files from multiple folders) is in plan, you should pay attention to duplicate file base names (in different folders).